# Google rich snippet testing not displaying reviews?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

I've been tinkering with this for hours, but to no avail! :) Need help!

I cannot get the reviews to show up in the rich snippet testing tool. I don't get any errors, but the PREVIEW snippet contains no reviews, although they are clearly in there and it is picking them up.

Any thoughts on this would be GREATLY appreciated:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.condolux.net%2Fatlantic-breeze-north-myrtle-beach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a question best asked on [Google's Structured Data forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/webmasters/structured-data), but it doesn't matter to me if I help you here or there.  :-) The problem is with your nesting.  You need to nest the aggregate rating schema within your Place schema.  And you should only be using one Place schema type for all of the related information, not two independent Place markups.

Comment: NESTING!! I had a hunch about that! Thank you so much for the suggestion.   SO, just so I am totally clear, I only need ONE place schema, and the aggregate rating schema needs to be WITHIN that place schema.  So based on that suggestion, I realize that I do have the aggregate within the place, and I went ahead and removed the OTHER place.  However, rich snippets testing tool is still not showing reviews. :( Any further thoughts by chance? I will continue to experiment though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still seeing two Place schema types, Paul. There are a couple of other things wrong with your markup as well.  Why don't you post this question on Google's structured data forum so that you don't upset anyone here with this type of question.  I'll be glad to help you there and go into more detail about what's wrong and what to do.

Comment: Thats a great idea, and I have done so.  I reverted back to the original, which is why you still see duplicate places. Alas, I have just posted on the forum and await any help. Thank you ever so much again for your guidance.